# NIC MAC address is different than it should be

Tags: wireless-networking, router, network-adapter, mac-address

I have cheap Tenda W150M router that is working as a WLAN card in Client+AP mode. The router MAC Address and WLAN BSSID are `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:68`(those are listed in the router admin page). Now on my main DLINK router 192.168.2.2 is listed as `xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-69`. Also Windows `arp -a` shows: `192.168.2.2 xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-69`. But if I call `netsh wlan show all` BSSID of this network is `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:68`.

Now to compare that to my DLINK router:

```
WLAN MAC Address is: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:54
netsh wlan show all: BSSID is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:54
arp -a: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:54
```

Now why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

On many Wi-Fi routers, the wireless and wired LAN ports are all bridged together and presented to the AP's IP stack as a single virtual interface. That single interface needs a single MAC address, so the software engineers have to pick one to use. Often they choose to use the wired LAN port's MAC address for that purpose. So it's quite common to see a Wi-Fi router's IP address resolve to a MAC address that's different than the MAC address of the radio you're associated to (that is, the BSSID).

If you're saying that the router admin page says that the wired Ethernet MAC address ends in 68, I think that's probably just a bug in the UI.

Comment: You might be right - probably it is a bug in the UI, but still `netsh wlan show all` shows `68`. Anyway what should I expect from cheap Tenda "router"...